# Azure Python SDK - code only fails when debugging in VS Code

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-keyvault

*VS Code 1.14.0, Python 3.8.0 (in venv).*

**When I run the following code in VS Code, it works.  When I run it in the debugger even with no breakpoints, it fails.  This might be something to do with venvs, but I don't know.  Ideas?  BTW - I am referencing the other packages for what I will be building.**

**From the Bash shell, I have the following environment variables:**

```
    export AZURE_TENANT_ID = "tenant ID"
    export AZURE_CLIENT_ID = "client ID"
    export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = "client secret"
    export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "subscription ID"
```

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
import datetime
import os

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://blahblahblah.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)

print(os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"])
print(os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"])
print(os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"])
print(os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"])

try:
    print("\n.. Get a Secret by name")
    secret = secret_client.get_secret("mySecret")
    print("Secret with name '{0}' was found with value '{1}'.".format(secret.name, secret.value))


except HttpResponseError as e:
    print("\nThis sample has caught an error. {0}".format(e.message))
```

**When I run this in DEBUG in VS Code, this is the error:**

```
This sample has caught an error.
No credential in this chain provided a token.
Attempted credentials:
        EnvironmentCredential: Incomplete environment configuration
        ImdsCredential: IMDS endpoint unavailable
        SharedTokenCacheCredential: The shared cache contains no signed-in accounts. To authenticate with SharedTokenCacheCredential, login
through developer tooling supporting Azure single sign on
```

**What I have learned is the printed OS environ variables are accurate when I Run Python File in Terminal, but when I run the file in debug, it errors printing the first OS environ variable saying it doesn't exist.**

This is my ignorance on setting debug correctly.  Any pointers will help (and thank you for your responses)!**

Comment: Most likely you have different environment variables. Check what you have configured for `AZURE_*` in each environment (native versus in the debugger). Edit your question with details on what type of credentials you have set up.

Comment: I see your new edit to the question. You missed the point of my comment. In your code `print` the values of the variables to compare between environements. Put those details in your question.

Comment: Again my ignorance.  When I added the "env" vars to the launch.json, it works in debugging.  Just exporting the vars into a bash shell didn't work because the debugger wasn't working within that shell.

Comment: You can add it to the answer. Then this issue can be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer shared in comment:

This issue occurred because of the missing of environment variables under debugger mode. Add the environment variables to the launch.json file solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, BASH does not like spaces, when declaring variables;

```sh
export AZURE_TENANT_ID="tenant ID"
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID="client ID"
export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="client secret"
export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="subscription ID"
```

*Might* do the trick.